# How to Fix: deprecation warning of 'any_instance'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, mocking, warnings

## My question

The scenario it works but in the console when I run the tests (`bin/rspec`) I get this warning:

> Deprecation Warnings:
>
> Using `any_instance` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead.
>    Called from /home/wakematta/github/example/spec/features/aspec/features/premium_spec.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in '.
>
> If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations to
>   identify where to make the necessary changes, you can configure
>   `config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
>   deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.
>
> 1 deprecation warning total

## My scenario

**`app/controllers/application_controller.rb`**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ExtraContent
end
```

**`app/controllers/concerns/extra_content.rb`**

```
module ExtraContent
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    helper_method :extra_content?
  end

  def extra_content?
    current_user.premium?
  end
end
```

**`app/views/users/show.html.haml`**

```
%h1= @user.name
- if extra_content?
  %span.premium PREMIUM
```

**`spec/features/premium_spec.rb`**

```
feature 'Premium features' do
  scenario 'premium user can view extra content' do
    ApplicationController.any_instance.stub(:extra_content?).and_return(true)

    visit '/users/1'
    expect(page).to have_content 'PREMIUM'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

**`spec/features/premium_spec.rb`**

```
feature 'Premium features' do
  scenario 'premium user can view extra content' do
    ApplicationController.any_instance.stub(:extra_content?).and_return(true)

    visit '/users/1'
    expect(page).to have_content 'PREMIUM'
  end
end
```

For this:

**`spec/features/premium_spec.rb`**

```
feature 'Premium features' do
  scenario 'premium user can view extra content' do
    allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:extra_content?).and_return(true)

    visit '/users/1'
    expect(page).to have_content 'PREMIUM'
  end
end
```